# Remove tkinter Slider overlay

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, slider

I have this slider :

```py
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as Tk
else:
    import tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()

w = Tk.Scale(root, from_=1, to=10, orient=Tk.HORIZONTAL,showvalue=0,sliderlength = 10,bd=0,bg="#3399ff",activebackground = "#3399ff", sliderrelief="solid")
w.set(3)
w.grid(row=2, column=1,sticky="W")

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", sys.exit)
root.mainloop()
```

and I can't figure out how to remove the little bars on it (the thick black lines in the picture).

[image: image showing the slider]

Do anyone know if there is a way to do it without using tttk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `sliderrelief="flat"` instead of `"solid"` I'm getting this as a result:

[Completely blue silder instad of black bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9S72.png)

I's this what you meant?